# How to implement windows azure caching on local database?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-connect

I am working on windows azure with asp.net mvc as a web role. I am trying to connect to my local database from the window azure and i successfully connected to my local database. Now my website performance is poor since my table has lot of records. In order to increase performane i have decided to use windows azure cache. I need to show all records in a table with CRUD operations and for every time  manipulation on data i need to do the manipulations on the cached version of data. I have followed some links from msdn,

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/wazplatformtrainingcourse_buildingappswithcacheservice_topic4#_Toc310505084

But i dont get full clarity on what to do. so please guide me to achieve windows azure caching on local database.

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial was very helpful for me when I came across this issue
http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/controllers-and-routing/improving-performance-with-output-caching-cs

Particularly this in the web config

```
    <caching>
      <outputCacheSettings>
        <outputCacheProfiles>
           <add name="Cache1Hour" duration="3600" varyByParam="none"/>
        </outputCacheProfiles>
      </outputCacheSettings>
    </caching>
```